# Regex to replace function foo(a,b) to function foo(b,a)

Tags: java, regex

I have function call like `BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination)`;

I want to change it to `BeanUtils.copyProperties(destination, source);` in many places. How to do it using Regex? What is the regex command to do this?

I'm using eclipse to do find and replace.

Comment: Are you trying to change it by find and replace in your code editor... if so, which editor? (I did not down vote you.)

Comment: It's very hard, almost impossible to do this with regex. Consider using a Java parser. For example `BeanUtils.copyProperties("..\",..)..",a)`.

Comment: don't use a regex, replace `(source,` with `(destination,`, then replace `, destination)` with `, source)` this would get most of them if your code is formatted the same way everywhere. Then you can try looking to see if any were left out

Comment: The thing is, source and destination is not same in all the places. It can be any word. I just want to swap the `$2` place to `$1`. I'm able to find it using `BeanUtils.copyProperties([\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?);`. But, how to swap it? Dear D.B, as per your previous post, any possibility like `BeanUtils.copyProperties($2, $1);`?

Comment: what are the possible values for "source" and "destination"? will it always be a simple alphanumeric variable name, or might it be a complex Java expression? Consider `new Source("parse this with regex buddy :-)")`

Comment: I made an update to my answer to match for other variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for (with regex setting turned on)

```
BeanUtils\.copyProperties\s*\(\s*([\w\_]+)\s*\,\s*([\w\_]+)\s*\)\s*\;
```

And replace with:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties($2, $1);
```

First escape all literal characters with backslash `\`

Wherever a space can be found when writing code, match it with 0 or more spaces. That by using `\s*` Could use `[ ]*` but `\s` might be sufficient in this case.

Then add captures for the source and destination by adding them in brackets. Or use `[\w\_]+` to match other variable names. With a `+` to mean at least 1 char. NB: if your variable have any other non-alphanumeric chars, add them to the `[...]` list.

Finally in the replace, switch the captures.

Comment: Answers without explanation are not very useful. (`\s*` matches zero or multiple spaces, and some capturing group stuff)

Comment: Good point on matching multiple lines... Let me add an explanation

Comment: it's not literally "source" and "destination"... those are expressions. otherwise OP could do a simple search+replace without regex

Comment: Oh, I thought it was literal. Will add the code to find other possibilities.

Comment: Excellent. The given solution works great. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Have a great day!